# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogController]

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I was running the project in localhost during the development, I was not getting any error with URL [www.websitename.com/admin/blog](http://www.websitename.com/admin/blog) but after uploading the project in Cpanel and hitting URL [www.websitename.com/admin/blog](http://www.websitename.com/admin/blog) I am getting error as...i uploaded all folder in cpanel

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogController] does not exist.
```

Comment: Make sure you have uploaded the entire vendor directory to your hosting

Comment: i have uploaded all the folder in Cpanel ...and after hitting the URL i got that error

Comment: post your route and controller code

Comment: is it linux hosting?

Comment: This error occurs because the server cannot read the BlogController.php file

You need to check that this file has been uploaded or not. Then check if the file's permissions are specified with read permission (example 755).